# Unity multiplayer UI button script

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have a multiplayer 2D game made in Unity and I wanted to put some onscreen buttons to be able to control it on the telephone. The problem is that when I put the Event Trigger on the button it uses the function from the script that has to use, but it can't open other functions called in the main one. In my code, I try to open the function TryFireBullet() whenever I am pressing the button and Debug.Log shows me that TryFireBullet() is opened, but the functions inside it are not opened at all. (when I press the button, Debug.Log() shows me "works", "works2" and no "works3"..)
Any ideas why it does not work and how to fix it? 
Here is the problem part of the code:

```
public void TryFireBullet()
{
    Debug.Log("works");
    //if (ultimul_glont == 0 || Time.time > ultimul_glont + Delay_Bullet)
    //{
        ultimul_glont = Time.time;
        Debug.Log("works2");
        CmdFireBullet();
    //}
}
[Command]
public void CmdFireBullet()
{
    Debug.Log("works3");
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, gunTip.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);
    RpcAdaugaViteza(bullet);
}
```

Here is the full code:
https://pastebin.com/WaWbQvTw

p.s. I can not use just a main function for my button because I need Server Commands

Comment: do you do this on the client or the host?

Comment: Both, one client will also be a server host and the other ones will be just clients. @derHugo

Comment: I mean did you try it on the client or the host? ... on the client the "works3" won't be called only on the host